# Magento2 Hide/Show VAT field based on Country

Tags: magento2

Can someone guide me on how to keep VAT field visible and required for non-USA countries and hide and not require for USA country on checkout page add address ?

I tried this way but its not working

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#co-shipping-form div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] select').change(function(){
        var cnt = jQuery(this).val();
        if ( cnt == 'US'){
            jQuery('#co-shipping-form [name="shippingAddress.vat_id"]').hide();
        }else{
            jQuery('#co-shipping-form [name="shippingAddress.vat_id"]').show();
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `jQuery('#co-shipping-form div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] select')` its seems you are  using wrong selector. can you add your html?

Comment: Its default Magento2 checkout page , add new address . FYI , When i run this script in console , its working fine

Comment: Is there any VAT for the USA?

Comment: > I get your code and it's work but after any change on country_id
> select. When I removed jQuery( document ).ready(function() { it's
> working also on first load.
> > require(['jquery'],function($){
> jQuery('#co-shipping-form div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] select').change(function(){
> var cnt = jQuery(this).val();
> if (cnt == 'US'){
> jQuery('#co-shipping-form [name="shippingAddress.vat_id"]').hide();
> }else{
> jQuery('#co-shipping-form [name="shippingAddress.vat_id"]').show();
> }
> }); }); It's not working. You musst need to update the JsLayout Proccessor via plugin.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138680)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138680)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138680)

Answer (score 1):

I get your code and it's work but after any change on `country_id` select.

When I removed `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {` it's working also on first load.

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
    jQuery('#co-shipping-form div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] select').change(function(){
        var cnt = jQuery(this).val();
        if (cnt == 'US'){
            jQuery('#co-shipping-form [name="shippingAddress.vat_id"]').hide();
        }else{
            jQuery('#co-shipping-form [name="shippingAddress.vat_id"]').show();
        }
    });
});
```

There is also second option, little more complex. You need to create 2 stores:

- first for US where you will disable VAT
- second for non US where you enable VAT

Option are availabe on:

- **Catalog**

  - **Customer Configuration**

    - **Create New Account Options**

      - **Show VAT Number on Storefront**.